# Is O(N+N) the same as O(2N) in Big O Notation?

Tags: math, runtime

If I have a program with two simple loops and nothing else, giving me O(N+N). With time complexities Big O Notation are we allowed to simplify O(N+N) as O(2N)? If not, do how do both differ in terms of time complexity. I apologize for the simple question but just got into studying these concepts and my study guide keeps using O(N+N) instead of O(2N), which is confusing me.

Comment: In fact `O(2N)` is `O(N)`.

Comment: Please post in meta stack exchange

Comment: @DilipD: No, please *don't* post in meta stack exchange as this question doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation is a very well known concept, and so there are tons of material available online.  One Google search away.  Not really sure why would you ask here.

In particular, Wikipedia has a very long article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

And there is a section on how sums work with this notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum

One common misunderstanding is to assume that `=` in the notation actually is an equality operation.  While, in fact, it is a set element operation, more commonly written as `∈`.

Technically, you should be writing `f(x) ∈ O(N)`.  Writing `f(x) = O(N)` is wrong, as `O(N)` is really a set of functions.  It is a set of all the functions that grow as fast as the linear function.

A sum of two functions that grow as fast as a linear function also grows as fast as a linear function.

`O(f)` is a set of functions that grow as fast as `f`.
Both `O(N+N)`, and `O(2N)` are the same sets as `O(N)`.
So, `O(N+N) = O(2N) = O(N)` and here, this `=` is really the set equality operation.